# Dask Distributed: Getting "AttributeError" after using setup.py install

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

Hello I wanted to build disk-distributed from scratch.

I read the ducumention [here](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/develop.html)

but after this steps I get the error
when I use `pytest distributed --verbose`

> File "/Users/bielefem/Dev/dask/distributed/distributed/**init**.py", line 3, in 
>       from . import config
>     File "/Users/bielefem/Dev/dask/distributed/distributed/config.py", line 13, in 
>       config = dask.config.config
>   AttributeError: module 'dask' has no attribute 'config'

using python repl shows:

```
>>> import dask

>>> dir(dask)
    ['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__git_revision__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', '__version__', '_version', 'absolute_import', 'base', 'callbacks', 'compatibility', 'compute', 'context', 'core', 'delayed', 'division', 'get', 'hashing', 'is_dask_collection', 'istask', 'local', 'optimization', 'optimize', 'order', 'persist', 'print_function', 'set_options', 'sharedict', 'threaded', 'utils', 'utils_test', 'visualize']

>>> dask.__version__
'0.17.4'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you have installed `distributed` from github.  As of 2018-05-12 the development version of `dask/distributed` needs the development version of `dask/dask`

Comment: Wow that was fast and correct. Thanks a lot you saved my day